# Unable to edit "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf" to get Windows Domain Users to login to Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop

Tags: lightdm, active-directory

Added Ubuntu 16.04 in Windows 2016 Domain. However not able to to edit `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf` and add `greeter-show-manual-login=true` line into that.

[image]

I have tried to achieve that using

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

However, after making the changes, not able to save it. 
The reason of editing that file is so that domain users can login to this Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to save it"? Do you get an error message, or don't you know how to save the changes with nano?

Comment: I use "Ctrl" X and then 'Y' to save. However i t gives a error saying Unable to save the changes. If you need the exact error (word by word) I can update that in some times.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson
I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Use another editor, gedit if you have it.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId , I have tried that too. 'gedit' error out saying that the file does not exists.

Comment: There is a spelling error in the path. And I don't see the `.conf` part either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when configuring *lightdm*, it's not a good idea to edit the existing files in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`, since they belong to various packages and changes will be overwritten next time respective package is updated. The recommended way is to create new files in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` instead.

In your case you can create such a file with a single command (copy and paste to get it right):

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[Seat:*]\ngreeter-show-manual-login=true\n" >/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-manual-login.conf'
```